# Too much recursion in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am getting a

> Too much recursion

error when I click on any event or date. Here is some of my code

```
$('#kt_calendar').fullCalendar({
  isRTL: false,
  header: {
    left: 'prev title next today',
    center: '',
    right: 'month,listMonth'
  },
  buttonText: {
    month: 'Calendar View',
    list: 'List View'
  },
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  navLinks: true,
  events: events,
  dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    load_day_events(date);
  },
  eventClick: function (info) {            
    if (info.id) {
      load_event(info);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This error normally happens when you raise an event from within an event handler. Is this occurring within either the `load_day_events()` or `load_event()` functions?

Comment: The browser console should show you a line number and/or stack trace of where the error occurred. That should help you narrow down the problem. As Rory says there's no obvious recursion in the code above...probably it's within one (or both) of the functions you haven't shown us. Please show us that code and a fuller report from the error, if you need more help. You might also want to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion . Thanks.

Comment: any solution for this?